# Extraction of 2d Curves using Image Filters

Tags: image-processing, filter, computer-vision, algorithm

I want to develop a program using Jpeg Loading Libraries only for Image Filters such as Recursive Gaussian, Add, Multiply, Join, Binary Magnitude and Eigen Analysis 2D to have a similar output of extraction of 2d curves. I will use visual studio 2008 C++ .net  windows form application. I can not use any other libraries just only "Jpeg Loading Libraries only".

any suggestion on which is the best jpeg loading library to use and good algorithm to have an extraction of 2d curves? thanks ^^

Answer (score 1):

.NET Framework itself contain JPEG format support - namely the GDI+ and WPF classes.

However, my favourite 3rd party library is [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) - it contains .NET Wrapper and OpenJPEG-based JPEG decoder.

Comment: gdi+ and wpf classes can support these filters Recursive Gaussian, Add, Multiply, Join, Binary Magnitude and Eigen Analysis 2D or still do i need to use a jpeg loading library? honestly i am confused. thanks brother

Comment: I thought you just need a JPEG decoder, not image processing library. This is something completely different.